# No space left on device when reading several HDFS files with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs

I'm trying to process information from different JSON line files stored in HDFS. The idea is that the code opens the file, processes it and then goes to the next file. The previous files won't be needed anymore. However, it doesn't seem like it's freeing any space at all when it finishes with each of the files. This is the code I'm using:

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkFiles

for i in range(0,2669):
    current = format(i, '04')
 
    hdfspath = "hdfs://myhdfspath/FILENAME00000000" + current + '.json'

    spark.sparkContext.addFile(hdfspath)
    currentfiletoopen = 'FILENAME00000000' + current + '.json'
    with open(SparkFiles.get(currentfiletoopen), 'rb') as handle:
        for line in handle:
            dict = json.loads(line)
            # do stuff with dict
            # ...
```

And the error that I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c95c99f0209a> in <module>
     28 
---> 29     spark.sparkContext.addFile(hdfspath)
     30     currentfiletoopen = 'FILENAME00000000' + current + '.json'
     31     with open(SparkFiles.get(currentfiletoopen), 'rb') as handle:

/opt/spark/dist/python/pyspark/context.py in addFile(self, path, recursive)
    914         [100, 200, 300, 400]
    915         """
--> 916         self._jsc.sc().addFile(path, recursive)
    917 
    918     def addPyFile(self, path):

/opt/spark/dist/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/spark/dist/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/spark/dist/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o172.addFile.
: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply$mcJ$sp(Utils.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$copyStream$1.apply(Utils.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1452)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyStream(Utils.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.downloadFile(Utils.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchHcfsFile(Utils.scala:842)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:815)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:601)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1614)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there any way to do this so that the already processed files stop taking up device space?

Comment: Keep in mind that the process the way you set it up streams all the files data through your driver, thus, being limited by the drivers ressources. Additionally, Python does not garbage collect. However, after closing the with-statement the handle should be released and the memory should be free for reallocation. Anyhow, have you tried opening the files on the nodes instead of the driver?

Comment: @Markus Sorry I'm quite new to all this. How can I force to open the files directly on the nodes instead of being streamed through the driver?